# Find records with the condition from other model rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `Bank` and `Rating` models. Bank has many ratings. Also, bank can be active and inactive (when it's license is suspended).

Inactive bank has date field (`license_suspended`) in DB with the date, when license was suspended. Active banks has `nil` in this field.

I need to find ratings only for active banks. I can find all banks with `license_suspended: nil` and then find associated rating with current date and add it one-by-one to array, but I think there is a better way to do it. I need something like this:

```
@ratings = Rating.where(date: Date.today.beginning_of_month, bank: bank.license_suspended.blank?)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `bank: bank.license_suspended.blank?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings

  scope :active, -> { where(license_suspended: nil) }
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bank
end
```

I think this will do what you want:

```
Rating.joins(:bank).where(date: Date.today).where(bank: {license_suspended: nil})
```

Or this:

```
Rating.joins(:bank).where(date: Date.today).merge(Bank.active) //this way you reuse active scope from Bank model
```

This will result in the following query:

```
SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings" INNER JOIN "banks" ON "banks"."id" = "ratings"."bank_id" WHERE "ratings"."date" = 'today_date' AND banks.license_suspended IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Ratings belong to a Bank, this looks like it'll do what you want:

`Rating.joins(:bank).where(date: Date.today.beginning_of_month, bank: {license_suspended: nil}`